# Python asynchronous module for cryptography?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, cryptography, python-asyncio

I'm creating an asyncio dependent application that needs to use encryption. I've searched but I can't find any crypto modules that use async. Do any exist or am I going to have to make an async fork of an existing library?

Comment: As far as I understand, cryptography is inherently CPU-bound, so there's no need to make it async.

Comment: In modules that support async, CPU-bound tasks are usually spawned to new thread. There is a need however regardless of that since you wind up needing to pass coroutines to the crypto module.

Comment: I got around it by awaiting `loop.run_in_executor()`

Comment: `run_in_executor` is exactly what you want to run CPU-bound code. You might want to post an answer and accept it.

Comment: It will have to use a ProcessPoolExecutor if it's CPU-bound.